# Some error in the code - libpcap

Tags: c, network-programming, pcap, libpcap

I'm trying to parse a pcap file in C. I don't want to use libpcap. But for some reason, I'm unable to. Do you know how can I do this ? Here is my attempt :

```
fseek(f,24,0);
while(count<20)//reading 20 packets
{ 
  fread(header,sizeof(struct pcap_pkthdr),1,f);
  //after this I'm printing values header fields
  fseek(f,ntohl(header->caplen),1);
  count++;
}
```

Output is not the same as libpcap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct pcap_pkthdr` is *NOT* the structure that defines the format of packet headers in a pcap file; it's the structure that defines the format of packet headers as provided to programs using libpcap or WinPcap.

The structure that defines the format of packet headers in a pcap file is *NOT* in any of the pcap include files, because libpcap/WinPcap provides routines that read those headers and transforms them as necessary to `pcap_pkthdr` headers.  Unlike `struct pcap_pkthdr`, the time stamp in packet headers in a pcap file always have a 32-bit "seconds" field and a 32-bit "microseconds" field, even on systems where `time_t` and the `tv_sec` value in a `struct timeval` are 64 bits.

I.e., the structure is defined by

```
struct pcap_timeval {
    bpf_int32 tv_sec;           /* seconds */
    bpf_int32 tv_usec;          /* microseconds */
};


struct pcap_sf_pkthdr {
    struct pcap_timeval ts;     /* time stamp */
    bpf_u_int32 caplen;         /* length of portion present */
    bpf_u_int32 len;            /* length this packet (off wire) */   
};
```

where `struct pcap_sf_pkthdr` is the structure in the file.

Note also that, if you read a `struct pcap_sf_pkthdr` from a file, you will have to byte-swap `ts.tv_sec`, `ts.tv_usec`, `caplen`, and `len` *IF* the file was written on a machine whose byte order differs from the machine on which you're reading the file.  Something as simple as `ntohl()` will *NOT* work - if, for example, your file was written on the same machine as the one on which you are reading it, no byte-swapping is necessary.

The *ONLY* way to make that work would be to *READ* the file header, rather than just skipping over it with `fseek()`.  If the "magic number" in the file header has the value `0xa1b2c3d4`, then you do not need to do any byte swapping; if it has the value `0xd4c3b2a1`, you will need to byte-swap the values in the file header and the `struct pcap_sf_pkthdr`.  Note that `ntohl()` and `htonl()` will *NOT* byte-swap if you're running on a big-endian machine such as a PowerPC/Power Architecture machine or a MIPS machine or an IBM mainframe or....

Note also that not all capture files are going to be pcap files; if they're pcap-NG files, they have to be read in a completely different fashion.  Libpcap 1.1 and later know how to read pcap-NG files (the libpcap/WinPcap API isn't powerful enough to handle *all* pcap-NG files, but it can, for example, handle pcap-NG files that only have one section and only have packets from one network adapter, and libpcap 1.1 and later can read those).  I would suggest, just as unwind suggested, that you use libpcap/WinPcap to read capture files, rather than writing your own code to do it.

Comment: I checked the magic number for this pcap file. It came out to be 0xa1b2c3d4. So it means I need not byte-swap from your explanation. But when i print the value of caplen of the first packet, it comes out to be as 0x1050d300 whereas the snaplen is 0xffff. how is this possible? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: For *that* file, you don't need to byte-swap; for other files, you might have to.  As for the caplen, you *DID* modify your code to read into a `struct pcap_sf_pkthdr`, as per my example, rather than a `struct pcap_pkthdr`, right?  If not, do so.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are correctly handling the endianness of the pcap file format.

Also, directly loading entire structures from disk is rarely safe, since compilers are free to insert padding between structure fields, which will make the bytes from disk not match the bytes in memory.

I would suggest you use the official library, since then those problems will already have been taken care of.

Comment: from what I observe, when I add caplen to the file pointer, it is quitting after first time. SO i thought may be i had to convert it to host byte order. So I used ntohl(caplen) but it made no diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
struct dump_pcap_pkthdr {
struct          timeval ts; /* time stamp */
unsigned int    caplen;     /* length of portion present */
unsigned int    len;        /* length this packet (off wire) */
};

struct dump_pcap_file_header {
unsigned int    magic;
unsigned short  version_major;
unsigned short  version_minor;
int             thiszone;   /* gmt to local correction */
unsigned int    sigfigs;    /* accuracy of timestamps */
unsigned int    snaplen;    /* max length saved portion of each pkt */
unsigned int    linktype;   /* data link type (LINKTYPE_*) */
};


static void read_pcap_file(char *file)
{
int fd    = -1;
struct dump_pcap_pkthdr packet_header    = {0};
struct dump_pcap_file_header pcap_header = {0};

fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
if(fd < 0) {
    printf("Fail open file: %s\n", file);
    return;
}

if(read(fd, &pcap_header, sizeof(pcap_header)) != sizeof(pcap_header)) {
    printf("Failed to read TCPDump Header from file: %s\n", file);
    return;
}

while(1)
{
    r = read(fd, &packet_header, sizeof(packet_header));
    if(r != sizeof(packet_header))
        break;

    //print data           

    lseek(fd, packet_header.caplen, SEEK_CUR);
}

close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Its the same as my implementation, rigt?

Comment: the above code is not working. It quits after first loop. I suspect there is something wrong in lseek( the caplen). Can you tell me whats going wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using non-standard functions instead of C standard ones?

Comment: @ALL: when I add caplen to the file pointer should I perform some conversion?

Comment: @Lundin Which one is non-startard function?

Comment: @user1192671 What means "not working"? Is it reading the first header right way?